# Full Calendar select option values to render list below the calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I would like to add some features wherein when you select an event option event it will render a list below the calendar, I already have working eventclick icon in the calendar, that each time you click an event date in the calendar a list will appear below the calendar. I would like to add some filter features such as select option that when you you changed it a list of all events will appear in the same class  'order-details-table'. I have stored the events_selector reference  as 'tags' in the events.

```
<select id="event_selector"> 
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="whiskey">Whiskey</option>

</select>
<div id="#eventdetails" class="order-details-table">&nbsp;</div>

    events:[

     title: 'Event Name',
     tags:'whiskey',
     products:
        [
          {
          name:'Event Place',
          url:'',
          time:'Sept. 15 | 12:00 PM',
          location:'TBA'

          }

        ]

  },

  ]


  $('event_selector').change(onSelectOpenList);
  function onSelectOpenList(){
    return['all', event.tags].indexOf($('#event_selector').val());

    function insert(title, product, url, time, location , tags){
        $(".order-details-table").append('<tr><td class="o-box-name"><a name="detailsevent">'+ product +'</a></td><td class="o-box-name">'+title+'<br><small>'+time+'</small><small>&nbsp'+location+'</small></td><td><a href="'+ url +'" class="cancel-del-text" target=_"blank">Register!</a></td></tr>'+tags);
      };

      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".calendar").offset().top }, 1500);

      $(".order-details-table").empty(); // Clear list of products
      for (var i = 0; i < calEvent.products.length; i++) {
        insert(calEvent.title, calEvent.products[i].name, calEvent.products[i].url,  calEvent.products[i].time,  calEvent.products[i].location, calEvent.tags);
      }
```

};

Comment: So you want to have a sort of overview below the calendar, that, whenever you click a date, will show all events from that date?

Comment: apologies for the confusion I already have that I just want to populate a list below the calendar for whatever values they got on the <select> option.

Comment: Select as in: the events that the user selected on the calendar? What do you mean with the <select> option?

Comment: <select id="event_selector"> 
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="whiskey">Whiskey</option>

</select> here when they slect whiskey all of the events that has tags:'whiskey' will populate below the calendar

Comment: Ok and what have you tried so far? Start by handling the "change" event of the select. Then get all events on the calendar using fullCalendar's "clientEvents". You can use the provided callback option to provide a function which will filter the response to those events which contain the tag value you're interested in. Then you can loop through the final results and create some HTML for them, and display it below your calendar. The logic is not so hard. Have you done anything towards this yet? I think now I've explained the process you should be able to make a good attempt at it?

Comment: @ADyson , yes I have edited the code above,

Comment: it sort of makes some sense, but I don't see where you call the fullCalendar "clientEvents" method as I suggested, so I don't see how you can ever get a list of current events in the calendar. Some of your variables also appear to be undefined. Also your function onSelectOpenList returns on its first line, so none of the rest of it will ever be executed.